# Soap returning PDO object as stdClass object

Tags: php, soap, pdo, wsdl

I am using web services (using SOAP and WSDL) for connecting to a database (PDO connection) and for running queries. I would like the PDO object to remain global throughout my application for executing queries. But on sending the PDO object after the database connection, the SOAP response I get is a stdClass object and not a PDO object. How do I get a PDO object as a soap response? Please help.

Comment: Would the PDO object not remain on the server side? You can't pass a database connection via a web service as it's a resource, not a data type.

Comment: Okay. That means I can just do the connection on the server side using PHP and then use services to execute queries using the PDO object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get a soap object as a PDO object. SOAP is a protocol based on XML, and when PHP parses the XML it creates stdClass.

If you want to 'convert' stdClass to a PDO object, you have to write your own code.

Comment: In that case it's a headache... :) And I think stdClass cannot be converted to a PDO object... Am I right?

Comment: Why not? Create a PDO object and use the stdClass properties to configure the PDO object.

Comment: Right. I am pretty new to PHP, can you help me in figuring out how to do that?

Comment: I suggest you open a new question and post a dump of the stdClass you receive.

Comment: On dumping I get object(stdClass)#4 (0) { }. And through the SOAP response I get <value xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct"/>

Comment: You get a empty message. You expect a Struct, but there are no properties?